# gcc -g flag: Moving the Source Code

Tags: c, gcc, gdb, objdump

My understanding is that when you compile C code using `gcc -g`, gcc will insert debugging information that includes references to the original source code (e.g. line numbers). Then other programs such as gdb and objdump can recover these references later on. For sake of an example, we'll use `objdump -S` which prints assembly interleaved with corresponding source code.

My goal is to copy the compiled binaries to a different computer and still be able retrieve this debug information. Currently, though, when I do this all of the debugging information is lost. I don't mind copying over the source files as well, but the second computer is running a different OS, so the file structure is different and I can't place the source files in exactly the same absolute location, which prevents objdump from finding the source code. I looked at the binary and saw a section that looks like this interspersed with a bunch of binary:

`/home/path/to/source/code`

I tried editing that to match the new path to the source but it just made the binary invalid.

I also researched [gcc flags](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) hoping that one of them would allow specifying a relative path to the source code instead of an absolute path, but I couldn't find anything like that.

For reference, here is the sort of output that I'm hoping to get from `objdump - S`:

```
0804840b <main>:
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
 804840b:       8d 4c 24 04             lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
 804840f:       83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
 8048412:       ff 71 fc                pushl  -0x4(%ecx)
 8048415:       55                      push   %ebp
 8048416:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8048418:       51                      push   %ecx
 8048419:       83 ec 14                sub    $0x14,%esp
  for(int varName = 0; varName < 100; varName++){
 804841c:       c7 45 f0 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x10(%ebp)
 8048423:       eb 32                   jmp    8048457 <main+0x4c>
    for(int innerLoop = 0; innerLoop < 30; innerLoop++){
 8048425:       c7 45 f4 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0xc(%ebp)
 804842c:       eb 1f                   jmp    804844d <main+0x42>
      if(innerLoop == varName){
 804842e:       8b 45 f4                mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
 8048431:       3b 45 f0                cmp    -0x10(%ebp),%eax
 8048434:       75 13                   jne    8048449 <main+0x3e>
        printf("%d\n", innerLoop);
 8048436:       83 ec 08                sub    $0x8,%esp
 8048439:       ff 75 f4                pushl  -0xc(%ebp)
 804843c:       68 f0 84 04 08          push   $0x80484f0
 8048441:       e8 9a fe ff ff          call   80482e0 <printf@plt>
 8048446:       83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  for(int varName = 0; varName < 100; varName++){
    for(int innerLoop = 0; innerLoop < 30; innerLoop++){
 8048449:       83 45 f4 01             addl   $0x1,-0xc(%ebp)
 804844d:       83 7d f4 1d             cmpl   $0x1d,-0xc(%ebp)
 8048451:       7e db                   jle    804842e <main+0x23>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  for(int varName = 0; varName < 100; varName++){
 8048453:       83 45 f0 01             addl   $0x1,-0x10(%ebp)
 8048457:       83 7d f0 63             cmpl   $0x63,-0x10(%ebp)
 804845b:       7e c8                   jle    8048425 <main+0x1a>
 804845d:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
      if(innerLoop == varName){
        printf("%d\n", innerLoop);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note: Although I used objdump as an example of a program which uses information about the source file, it is not actually the output of objdump which I'm interested in. I'm running a different program which needs access to this same information. The question is about how to fix the binaries, not how to use objdump.

Comment: It doesn't look like `objcopy`, the usual way to modify object files, currently supports changing this. But gcc's `-fdebug-prefix-map` option ought to do what you want at compilation time. `cc foo.c -g -fdebug-prefix-map=$(pwd)=.` ought to output `.` instead of the pathname of the current directory (which is what you typically see) in the DW_AT_comp_dir attribute. Run `objdump -Wi foo` to check.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick This seems to work, thanks! If you put it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I would suggest using `gcc -S -fverbose-asm`  (probably also with `-g`  and/or `-O`) to get the assembler code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

gcc and clang, when generating debug info, will set the DWARF attribute `DW_AT_comp_dir`to the working directory for each compilation unit in the object file.

```
cc a.c b.c -g -o foo
objdump -Wi foo
```

will show something like

```
Contents of the .debug_info section:

  Compilation Unit @ offset 0x0:
 <0><b>: Abbrev Number: 1 (DW_TAG_compile_unit)
    <11>   DW_AT_name        : a.c
    <15>   DW_AT_comp_dir    : (indirect string, offset: 0x0): /home/user/src

  Compilation Unit @ offset 0x4d:
 <0><58>: Abbrev Number: 1 (DW_TAG_compile_unit)
    <5e>   DW_AT_name        : b.c
    <62>   DW_AT_comp_dir    : (indirect string, offset: 0x0): /home/user/src
```

The program usually used to transform object files, [objcopy](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objcopy.html), doesn't currently support changing these DWARF attributes.

But gcc and clang take an [-fdebug-prefix-map](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#index-fdebug-prefix-map) option, which ought to do what you want at compilation time.

Since gcc gets the current directory using libiberty's `getpwd` function, which uses the `PWD` environment variable (after checking it for correctness) in preference to libc's `getcwd`, we can get the same value by running the shell's `pwd -L` builtin.

```
cc a.c b.c -g -fdebug-prefix-map=$(pwd -L)=. -o foo
```

will output `.`, instead of the pathname of the current directory, in the `DW_AT_comp_dir` attribute.